# How do I set constraint for textLabel and detailTexLabel of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I want to do the same to put a well-defined constraint from left to the `UITableViewCell` elements.

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Starred")
if cell == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Starred") 
}
return cell!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i in my case i resized textLabel and imageView

```
import UIKit
class TableViewCellClass: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        //Here change your detailedTextLabel
        imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 15.0, width: 25, height: 25)//Change left menu table view image size
        imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 70, y: 12.5, width: 250, height: 30)//Change left menu table view text label size
    } else {
        //Here change your detailedTextLabel
        imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 12.5, width: 25, height: 25)//Change left menu table view image size
        imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 12.5, width: 200, height: 25)//Change left menu table view text label size
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the backgroundView frame OR something like backgroundView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and then use anchor constraints? I have tried both options and it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

I find in cases like this to programmtically layout your custom cell.

Also to keep your ViewController lean, create a subclass of your custom cell and override init method passing the .subtitle as a style.

Example:

```
class StarCell: UITableViewCell {
     override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, resuseIdentifier: String?) {
         super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

         self.detailTextLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         self.detailTextLabel?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
         self.detailTextLabel?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
         self.detailTextLabel?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

         self.detailTextLabel.text = "Testing Subtitle"
     }
}
```

Its pretty much the same for textLabel. Don't forget to set autoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false and because it is false you must set a height or width otherwise the label won't render. If you want the label height to be fluid based on screen size you can use the multiplier parameter when setting the constraints.

NB. Xcode will complain about needing the required init method, just click the red dot and fix. Xcode will automagically insert the code for you.